# how to pass my arguments to constructor function while testing using web3

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I need to test my contract using web3js and ganache-cli. In my contract, I have to send an argument to the `constructor` function. How to do it while deploying it with web3js?

```
factory = await web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(compiledFactory.interface))
    .deploy({
      data: compiledFactory.byteCode,
    })
    .send({
      from: accounts[0],
      gas: "1000000",
    });
```

And my contract is,

```
contract Factory{
    CrowdFunding[] public deployedContractAddresses;

    constructor(uint minimum) public {
        CrowdFunding newContract = new CrowdFunding(minimum, msg.sender);
        deployedContractAddresses.push(newContract);
    }

    function getDeployedContractAddresses() public view returns(CrowdFunding[] memory) {
        return deployedContractAddresses;
    }
}
```

I have gone through this [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/55594/deploying-contract-with-parameters-using-web3-js-and-node-js) in Ethereum.SE, but I'm not able to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by providing data to the `arguments` property of `.deploy()` function.

```
    contractInstance = await new web3.eth.Contract(interface).deploy({
        data: bytecode,
        arguments: [INITIAL_minimum]
    }).send({
        from: accounts[0],
        gas: 1000000
    });
```